# Service stack support for WIF

Tags: servicestack

I need to connect servicestack to ADFS, as well as the usual social id providers.  I know there are apps that could do this for me, authbridge, thinktecture, etc, but would really like to have everything within one app.

Is anybody working on adding a WIF authentication provider to servicestack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack hasn't added any specific support for WIF, but it looks like it maybe provided by a 3rd Party (Auth10) in their ServiceStack Auth NuGet package:

https://nuget.org/packages/Auth10.ServiceStack